# Any Javascript functions to get homepage ,search provider ,favourites etc from browsers like Firefox and google chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium

my application is  setting browserhome page ,search provider ,favourites etc to all supported browsers like googlechrome,firefox,internet explorer.My purpose is to automate my application using selenium .In case of IE these informationa are stored in registry . so it is easy for me to validate the above details .But for firefox and google chrome its bit problem .So i just want know whether there is any functions available in javascript to check browser homepage ,search provider,favourites etc in firefox and google chrome ?

Comment: One can read registry in Selenium? o_Ok. Navigate to `about:config` and then search corresponding settings. These actions could be reproduced with js in selenium, AFAIK.

Comment: Boy your application sounds awesome. Makes me miss Windows almost.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.  It would be a security and privacy issue if client side js code could access that information.  Instead you would need to use a browser extension, or in your case you can just use an external program with administrative rights.  I am pretty sure that selenium does not have this functionality built in, however it is all available if you know where the browser stores it.  IE uses the registry, but chrome and Firefox use proprietary files in their profile directories.  There may be an library that does this, otherwise it is possible

Comment: Ok guys ..thanks for your reply.i need to look for alternative ways as Sam mentioned